# CTRL+N Not invoking new on a DetailsFormTransactions Page

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need ***CTRL+N*** to invoke the default behavior, that is to create a new record without invoking my NewButton.

*NewRecordAction* property is not filled out, the shortcut does nothing, seems to be disabled.

The DataSource on the form allows create, I can create through my `NewButton MenuItemButton`.

I seem to have lost it's default behavior somehow, what could cause that?

Comment: You should provide details, Share your research. If your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl-N does not do anything, because the `NewRecordAction` is not filled out and because there is not a command button with `New` in the `Command` property.

I assume you have used "Create form from template" or have copied from the `SysBPStyle_TransactionDetails` form (same thing). This form contains a botton `NewButton` which is ment to call a creation form, like the `SalesCreateOrder` form.

You have two options:

1. Fill out the `NewRecordAction` with the control name of your create menu item. This should be mandatory in list pages.
2. Delete the `NewButton`, then create a new command button with `New` in the `Command` property. Also remember to assign a value to the `DataSource` property on the control or a containing node.

I personally prefer the second option (maybe combined with a `setFocus` call) because a create form is then not needed and there is only one form for you to maintain and the user to learn.